# No intellisense for dynamic keyword?

Tags: c#, com, silverlight-4.0

I am reading `Silverlight 4 in Action` and simultaneouly trying examples in it. However, i can't seem to understand the new `dynamic` keyword and why is it needed for `COM`. This is my code :-

```
 if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
            {
                dynamic excel =
                AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
                excel.Visible = true;
                dynamic workbook = excel.workbooks;
                workbook.Add();
                dynamic sheet = excel.ActiveSheet;
                int i = 1;
                double[] data = new double[] { 1.0, 5.0, 9.5, 2.7, 3.2, 0.6 };
                foreach (double d in data)
                {
                    dynamic cell = sheet.Cells[i, 1];
                    cell.Value = "Row " + i;
                    cell.ColumnWidth = 10;
                    cell = sheet.Cells[i, 2];
                    cell.Value = d;
                    i++;
                }
                dynamic shapes = sheet.Shapes;
                shapes.AddChart(-4100, 120, 2, 300, 200);
            }
```

I am wondering how did the author come to know that shapes support `AddChart` method and how did he know which parameters he needed to pass to this function? Can somebody throw some light on this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The author probably RTFM.  Then again, writing the code with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference added first, then editing it to use *dynamic* would be another approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not needed for COM.  However, the code that doesn't use `dynamic` is a real mess.

As to how the author knew what methods are available, he read the Excel VBA documentation.  Looking at the Excel type library would also tell you the method signatures, but without the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic basically means you don't know at compile time what type you will have (or sometimes the type doesn't even exist yet). Hence the absence of intellisense.

With a dynamic object you just call a method, throw in some parameters, and if that exact method with that signature exists, the [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime) will call it.

If it doesn't exist you'll get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

" method and how did he know which parameters he needed to pass to this function? "

He probable coded it or read the documentation.